# Read data from dynamic queue RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, api, rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ. I am pushing messages using dynamic queues using web API. Queue name created run time according title  ie: ABC001, 123XYZ, PQR, etc. Exchange is same for all queues. How can I access all queue list with multiple messages as per each queue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate your use case? Do you really need dynamic queue naming?

Comment: I am pushing data in to the queue. I have created on listener to read data from queue in a continue manner. But while accessing data from queue I am not able to push data in to the queue at same time.